# How to count commented cell in excel with VBA?

Tags: excel

I tried to count commented cells in excel with this vba code in **a column** , but it return **all** comment in **whole worksheet**. how I change this code to count cells only in one row or columns form n1..n2?

```
Function CountComments(xCell As Range)

    Application.Volatile
    CountComments = xCell.Parent.Comments.Count
End Function
```

example:

A1=CountComments(G2:G7)

A2=CountComments(H2:H7)

they return one result

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, It counts the number of cells that are having comments

```
Function CountComments(xCells As Range)

Dim x As Range
On Error Resume Next

For Each x In xCells
L = -1
L = Len(x.Comment.Text)
    If L >= 0 Then Counts = Counts + 1
Next

CountComments = Counts
End Function
```